Entire function whose Fourier transform is a linear combination of Dirac delta
The Paley-Wiener-Schwartz theorem states that an entire function $f$ is the Fourier transform of a compactly supported distribution $v$ if and only if
$$
|f(z)| = O(|z|^N e^{a|\text{Im}\ z|}) ,\qquad z \in \mathbb C.
$$
for $N$ the order of the distribution $v$ and $a>0$. I was wondering if in that case, $v$ is necessarily of the form
$$
v(z) = p(z) + \sum_{i, j} a_{i, j}\ \delta^{(i)}(z-z_j),
$$
where $p$ is a piecewise continuous function (necessarily of compact support) and the sum is finite.
In other words, is $v-p$ a finite linear combination of the Dirac delta and its derivatives?
An example of that would be $f(z) = \sin(z)(1/z + z)$ and $v(z) = \text{rect}(z) + \delta'(z-1) + \delta'(z+1)$.
If not, what is a counterexample of that? If the counterexample is pathological, there should be some natural additional assumptions that would eliminate them, so what would they be?
This looks related to Lebebegue's decomposition theorem.
